# How to do GPU Passthrough with windows 10 host to windows 10 guest (Virtual Machine)

Tags: virtual-machine, gpu

So I have this work computer that I'd like to play fortnite on, but it doesn't have the latest version of directX installed in it so I can't just install fortnite to my flashdrive and play.

So I've been researching on getting a portable Windows 10 Virtual Machine on my flashdrive, which has fortnite installed in the VM. However, apparently Virtual Machines don't utilize the host's GPU by default. I'm trying to find out a way to let the Virtual Machine use the native GPU. I've seen that it's completely doable on a Linux host, but I can't find anything about GPU passthrough on a windows10 host.

Note: my work computer does support VT-d, and it is locked down so I can't do anything to it that requires elevated privileges like installing stuff, changing the BIOS, or booting off an external harddrive.

Comment: Would it be an option to boot Linux from a USB drive and do it under Linux?

Comment: I can't boot off USB or any external storage: it's disabled on the BIOS